Multivariate Taylor in spherical coordinates
I want to expand a function in spherical coordinates. This question is motivated by electromagnetism. I would like to recover spherical multipole expansion from multivariate expansion of $\dfrac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}\ '|}$.
One of my physics textbooks expresses multivariate Taylor expansion as $f(x+\epsilon)=e^{\vec{\epsilon}. \nabla}(f)$, which I mention because it makes me think: I should be using spherical gradient?
This prompts a follow up question: if so, should I be using spherical metric to contract derivatives $\partial_{\mu_I}$ with $(\epsilon_\mu)^{\mu_I}$ terms or maybe instead of metric the weird $\sqrt{g_{\mu \nu}}$ that seems to be used more often in vector calc, which reduces to $\sqrt{g_{\mu \mu}}$ for spherical of course.
There is a similar question about Taylor expansions in spherical that has not been answered yet, FYI. Found here

The Taylor expansion (with appropriate numerical factors that that linked post is missing) is valid for any coordinate system, just as the "differential" expression $df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},dx_i$ holds for any coordinate system $(x_i)$. But turning the differential $1$-form into the gradient vector field does introduce factors from the metric, yes.
